# How can I use cell fracture to a limited section of the mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to fracture a mesh to a limited section. It is shown in this sketch:[image]

How can I control the width of this section and how can I let the top and the bottom of this mesh unmodified? How can I let the sections away from the fractured section the bits become larger and can I even make the fractured line be angled or bend?